# Question about integral on hypersurface

Tags: integration, surfaces

Let $S$ be a (n-1) dimensional hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I see something like this written:

> $$\int_S f(s)d\sigma(s)$$
>   where $d\sigma$ means the surface measure.

Now if $\Phi\colon T \to S$ is a diffeomorphism where $T$ is also another hypersurface, can I simply use the change of variables like so, with $s = \Phi(t)$, we have
$$\int_S f(s)d\sigma(s) = \int_T f(\Phi(t))|\text{det}D\Phi|d\sigma(t)$$

Is it right to write $d\sigma (t)$? Here $D\Phi$ is the matrix of partial derivatives of $\Phi.$

can I just ignore the differential and concentrate on manipulating the integral in whatever way I wish (like I would on usual integrals over intervals)?

Comment: is $D\phi$ the Jacobian matrix of transformation?(Referred here as 'matrix of partial derivative')

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: Then I think this is correct, putting all the technical mumbo-jumbo aside and looking at a 3 dimensional example, the Jacobian indeed transforms the double integral the same way.

Comment: Note that the ordinary surface integral gives a positive linear functional on $C_c(S)$, the space of continuous compactly supported functions on $S$, where $S\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ is locally compact Hausdorff. The [Riesz representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz–Markov–Kakutani_representation_theorem) furnishes a Riesz measure on the surface $S$.